# tibble full_join and conditionally replace NA

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm sorry I don't have a better subject line. I'm not 100% sure of the right terms. Given `foo` and `bar` below I want to produce `bam` via `full_join` (I think).

```
foo <- tibble(ID=rep(1:2,2),Longitude=c(-118,-117,-118,-117),Latitude=c(47,46,47,46),
              value=c(2,5,4,1),variable=rep(c("A","B"),2))
bar <- tibble(ID=rep(1:2,2),Elev=c(100,200,100,200),
              value=c(19,20,32,18),variable=rep(c("D","E"),2))
bam <- tibble(ID=rep(1:2,4),
              Longitude=c(-118,-117,-118,-117,-118,-117,-118,-117),
              Latitude=c(47,46,47,46,47,46,47,46),
              Elev = c(100,200,100,200,100,200,100,200),
              value = c(2,5,4,1,19,20,32,18),
              variable = c("A","B","A","B","D","E","D","E"))
# result is close to `bam`
res <- full_join(foo,bar,by=c("ID","value","variable"))
```

I want `res` to look like `bam` where the NA values in `res` are copied according to `ID`. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `full_join` you can `fill` by `ID`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

full_join(foo,bar,by=c("ID","value","variable")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = 'updown')

#     ID Longitude Latitude value variable  Elev
#  <int>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#1     1      -118       47     2 A          100
#2     2      -117       46     5 B          200
#3     1      -118       47     4 A          100
#4     2      -117       46     1 B          200
#5     1      -118       47    19 D          100
#6     2      -117       46    20 E          200
#7     1      -118       47    32 D          100
#8     2      -117       46    18 E          200
```